# grequests with requests has collision

Tags: python, django, ssl, python-requests, grequests

I am using grequests python module to call some APIs. I want to make two functions.

1. A single request(use requests module)
2. A multiple request(use grequests module)

When I use two modules in two different files, it runs normally, but when I import two modules in the same file, requests module fall in infinity recursive.

```
  #!/usr/bin/env python                                                                                                                                                                                          
  #-*- encoding:utf-8 -*-                                                                                                                                                                                        

  import requests                                                                                                                                                                                                
  import grequests                                                                                                                                                                                               

  def SingleRequest():                                                                                                                                                                                           
      rs = requests.get("www.example.com")                                                                                                                                                                          
      return rs                                                                                                                                                                                             

  def MultiRequest():                                                                                                                                                                                            
      urls = [                                                                                                                                                                                                   
          "www.example1.com", 
          "www.example2.com",  
          "www.example3.com"                                                                                                
      ]                                                                                                                                                                                                          
      rs = [grequests.get(u) for u in urls]                                                                                                                                                        
      rs_map = grequests.map(rs);                                                                                                                                                                                
      return rs_map;
```

If I call MultiRequest() -> do Well!

but if I call SingleRequest() ..... ↓

```
Exception Type: RecursionError
Exception Value: maximum recursion depth exceeded
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.6/ssl.py in options, line 459

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/ssl.py in options
     super(SSLContext, SSLContext).options.__set__(self, value) X 100 times...
```

Is it possible to use requests and **grequests** in one file?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes.
Import **requests** after **grequests**.
Here is an [open issue](https://github.com/kennethreitz/grequests/issues/103) about this.

```py
import grequests   # noqa: F401
import requests
```

Comment: When there is an issue, this fixes it. When there is no issue, this gives **good** performance, contrary to the other solution.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me (Python 3.8.6, a module needed imports of `grequests` and `requests`) ([source](https://github.com/spyoungtech/grequests/issues/103#issuecomment-286117061)). This should precede all other imports:

```
from gevent import monkey
def stub(*args, **kwargs):  # pylint: disable=unused-argument
    pass
monkey.patch_all = stub
import grequests
```

Comment: When there is an issue, this fixes it. When there is no issue, this gives **bad** performance, contrary to the other solution which I prefer.